# Lock screen PIN detection on WinPhone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am writing an App with some reasonably sensitive data in it. At the moment is uses a forms based login page, username and password. I currently cache the username but not the password - forcing the user to type it in each time.

One of my users has pointed out that if they already lock the phone with a PIN, it is not much less safe to cache the password as well.

So, can you detect whether a WinPhone8 device is using a PIN on the lock screen?

Comment: Why not store the password encrypted? Also storing the password in even plain text is pretty safe for WP

Comment: My concern is not how to store it but whether to store it. Caching the password allows anyone who finds an unlocked phone to access the sensitive personal data of young people held in the app. By not caching the password, it forces the legitimate user to type in their password each time which is "safer".

Comment: Or, you could offer your own PIN lock so users would not have to enter a complex password everytime. It would be their choice. You could also have a "Remember me" option when entering the password. This is a dilemma when saving passwords on the system whether in your app or in a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no API available which will tell you whether the user has set a PIN on the lock screen from within an app.